# Hide overflow on elements with fixed position

Tags: css, web, position, overflow

Is there any way to hide the overflow of a **fixed** div with a container? I thought fixed inside fixed would do it, but it seems it's not the case. The only workaround I can think of is "inverted" masks: other fixed divs hiding everything *around* the one, but it'd be better if there are any other solutions.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjFa6/1/

Comment: Remove the fixed from the inner div, and add `position: relative;` to them. http://jsfiddle.net/pjFa6/12/

Comment: The question only refers to divs with fixed position.

Comment: In that case the only thing I can think of is setting the inner div to position absolute instead of fixed. http://jsfiddle.net/pjFa6/15/. You can't nest a fixed element and have it contained within it's wrapping element as far as I can tell. You would have to mask it, which wouldn't be very nice.

Comment: @Jeemusu Thanks, please you post your comment as an answer so I accept it

Comment: Strangely [this is possible](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/n8TpR/21/) with `z-index` in safari 6.1.4… :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems to be impossible to nest a fixed element within another element (fixed or not) and expect the outer element to wrap it and hide any overflow.

The only thing I can think of is setting the inner div to `position:absolute` instead of fixed. Here is an example based on your jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/pjFa6/15](http://jsfiddle.net/pjFa6/15) .

Comment: it is achievable instead.. look here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463658/parent-child-with-position-fixed-parent-overflowhidden-bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463658/parent-child-with-position-fixed-parent-overflowhidden-bug)

Answer (score 1):

with a `z-index: any value;` statement in the container will do in some webkit browsers, like chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In some mobile browser contexts, use of `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` may achieve a "clipped" fixed-position element. See: https://miketaylr.com/posts/2015/06/position-fixed-overflow-hidden.html