# Make fixed element obey overflow:hidden

Tags: css, position

Actually can't quite believe I can't solve this!

How can I get a fixed element to obey the `overflow` setting?

I have done a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/REk4C/7/

[image]

In the fiddle and the above image, you'll see a `div` that contains three `div`s, each have a different `position` setting. The `relative` element obeys the overflow. Now I would expect and can accept that the `absolute` element to break out, but I need the fixed element to obey the `overflow` is this possible?

Happy to use jQuery if needed.

Comment: the fiddle seems not to be complete, some of the classes used are missing

Comment: I don't understand.. This is the expected behavior according to the w3schools css positioning: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp. It's ok that it only work with `position: relative`.

Comment: True i agree it's expected behavior. Just wondered if anyone had any dirty fixes. I think i may have found the dirty fix im after

Comment: There's an explanation to your issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463658/parent-child-with-position-fixed-parent-overflowhidden-bug hope it helps

Comment: If your child div is inside a fixed positioned div, why are you specifying its position as fixed? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed and absolute positioned elements are taken out of the normal document flow, what means the borders of the original parent container have no influence on the element anymore.

Comment: Slightly incorrect, an absolutely-positioned element *can* be clipped by its parent, if the parent is `relative` – however a fixed element cannot, under any circumstances, be constrained.

Comment: So @derrylwc, Is there any sensible way to make an absolutely-positioned element within a relative-container behave as if it was fixed?

Comment: If the parent element were 100% width/height of the viewport, then technically the `absolute` child would behave as if it were fixed. But for all intensive purposes, you must either remove `relative` from the parent, or simply use `fixed` if you want to position an element relative to the viewport.

Answer (score -1):

To fix the absolute positioned div, create a new position context in the container:

```
#wrap {height:100px; width:100px; border:20px solid red; overflow:hidden;position:relative;}
```

The fixed positioned div goes completely out of the flow (and potentially outside the container box), so it is not possible. To demonstrate, make the fiddle window really small, and scroll the window vertically, and observe the fixed div moving outside the container.

Comment: It seems your goal is really unclear! What are really trying to achieve with the fixed positioned div?