# Overflow hidden not functioning after jquery animation (in chrome)

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Here is my scenario:

I've got a div container with `overflow: hidden`.
Within this div is an element with `position: fixed`. 
On the background a Jquery plugin loads and animates thumbs of images. 
(for the sake of this explanation i will put it inline)

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">
  <div style="position: fixed"> </div>
</div>
```

Now, the overflow:hidden works for as long as the thumbs are running there animation. After the animation is done the element will overlay all other divs on the page. This issue might be specific to my plugin but I figured it might as well be a jquery/chrome thing. Either way any pointers are greatly appreciated! :)

To see what I'm referring to please check: http://rendezvous.nu and scroll down. Bellow story you will find a timeline and lots of thumbs. Scroll it just so that the timeline overlay's the story and refresh.

Thanks!

Comment: `overflow: hidden` typo? check above code again..

Comment: on the second div, shouldn't it also be position:fixed? not just fixed...

Comment: position fixed is relative to the viewport not the div it is within

Comment: @Mr_Green Thanks, I will correct that. The typo is just in the example not in the site mentioned. Same goes for position fixed, thanks

Comment: @Pete this is not a problem as long as the overflow would hide the element. This works fine in Firefox en IE. Please check my link for reference.

Comment: @JasonSchot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463658/parent-child-with-position-fixed-parent-overflowhidden-bug

Comment: @Pete I checked that but that did not answer it for me since it does work in firefox & IE. Now that I'm checking i'm guessing the proper structure in my case should be: 
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="container" style="position: relative;">
     <div style="position: fixed;"> </div>
  </div>
</div>

Hope that makes sense

Comment: I think the point being made is that different browsers may handle it differently but the correct way for it to be handled is probably the one that you would call incorrect.

Comment: Could you please explain this incorrect way?