# Overflow stops working when z-index is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow, z-index

I have a container div with **overflow:hidden** wrapping a bunch of smaller divisions. They all have  **z-index: 1** including the container. All are positioned **fixed**.

When I change the size of the smaller divisions, overflow works fine and clips the smaller divisions that would exceed the container's boundary (fig. 1).

With jQuery, I change the z-index of the container to bring it forward, and everyone follows *except that the container's overflow stops working*. The inner divs overflow. (fig. 2)

[Link to screencap](http://michelpoisson.net/_HTML/images/overflow_z-index_bug.png).

And when I return the container **to z-index:1,** it and its children go back behind the other page elements where they should be. No problem with z-index.

Except that overflow remains broken. (fig. 3)

I've tried directly re-issuing an **overflow:hidden** to the container, using classes to set overflow and z-index, and nothing seems to work. Has anyone encountered something like this?

Edit: This only happens in Chrome - all work fine in Safari - not Moz-proof yet.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/12463736/711902, `overflow: hidden` shouldn't work at all for fixed-position elements. Are child elements' positions fixed or absolute? You probably want the parent to have fixed position, and child elements to have absolute position.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. Will see if I can have my setup with child position absolute - but I'm pretty sure I've tried just about every position combo possible...

Comment: ...60 seconds later: it totally solved it! Apparently that's one combination I hadn't tried.

Answer (score 0):

Make the children `position: absolute`, but keep the parent `position: fixed`. The children will stay put when you scroll, but it will allow the parent's `overlow: hidden` property to clip the children out of view.