# Fixed Background-image jumps after zooming on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, browser

I tried so much! But I think my problem is a little more special than the other solved questions:

Here is the side: 
fruehstarter.com

I have a problem with the background on mobile devices.
My client wanted a special background, it's fixed with 100% width and height. On a mobile device you need to zoom in to identify the content. 
But if you scroll down and the browser line disappears, the background-image jumps because of the new height.

Either I have the jumping background or I have a white border at the end of the side with the height of the browser line.

Hope you understand my problem and can help me. Thanks a lot!

EDIT: What I've tried:

[background:cover not scaling on mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878136/backgroundcover-not-scaling-on-mobile-browsers)

[Background image jumps when address bar hides iOS/Android/Mobile Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944925/background-image-jumps-when-address-bar-hides-ios-android-mobile-chrome)

And I've tried to give my div ".bg" and ".container-fluid" another positions (changed to "absolute" and "relative") or give another div the background.

EDIT 2nd:

Here is the CODE: [jsfiddl](https://jsfiddle.net/kv4ec90z/1/)

```
HTML:
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="bg"></div> 
   <div class="row">
    <div class="linkbox"></div>
   </div>
 </div>

CSS:

 html {
  font-size: 10vh;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
 }

 body {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
 }

 .container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
 }

 .row {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
 }

 .bg {
  overflow: hidden; 
  position: fixed; 
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 10rem;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  z-index: -1; 
  background: url('http://fruehstarter.com/wp- content/themes/fruehstarter/library/images/fs_klingelschildMobil6.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size:cover;
  -moz-background-size:cover;
  -o-background-size:cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
 }

JAVASCRIPT:

 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod|Android)/g)) {
    $('html').css('font-size', Math.ceil($(window).height() / 10));
    $('.bg').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
    $('body').scrollTop(1);
  }
 }
```

Comment: _"I tried so much!"_ - What have you tried? Please provide us with some code and maybe even a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example

Comment: I have shared my code, maybe it's easier to undderstand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to share your code.

I think

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

in addition is what your are looking for.

Example:

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

**Update**

Try this:

```
     body {
         background: url('http://fruehstarter.com/wp- content/themes/fruehstarter/library/images/fs_klingelschildMobil6.jpg') no-repeat;
         background-size: cover;
         -webkit-background-size:cover;
         -moz-background-size:cover;
         -o-background-size:cover;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-position: center;
         background-attachment: fixed;
     }
```

I think defining background inside the body, in your case, is more comfortable.

Comment: It is more comfortable to define your background inside the "body"-element. Because "body" by nature is full size.

Comment: I change it like you say, but it had no impact.