# Animating text color that matches the background color with CSS or SVG?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am not sure if here is the best place to ask such question. But I have very little clue where to start with this and would appreciate if someone could point me to the right place.

And not sure what's the best search term for this.

I am trying to re-create such typography effect. If you look at "Organic", it changes fill color and spacing as the user scroll down the page. The fill color is filling half way in the text.
https://dribbble.com/shots/2623261-Landing-Page-Animation

Is CSS possible? Or SVG? If yes, what areas should I be investigating?

---

*Updated: I have found the article for this.
https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with CSS.
Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484858/css-change-color-on-scroll-cut-text-overflow-z-index). It is simple effect.

Basically, you add multiple text. One with white and one with black color in different div and you add clipping to each div, so when you scroll, it appears like the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks! That's even simpler.