# Why is "fixed" element not respecting its parent's borders?

Tags: html, css

I have a fairly simple problem, but still I couldn't find any solutions so far:

Having a *parent* div with fixed `width` (and also `overflow-x: auto`).

This div contains a *child* div which has `position:fixed` and fixed `width` (larger than container).

Pretty simple. I wish the child to be never visible outside of parent.

I.e.: make the red never go beyond borders of parent: https://jsfiddle.net/aqdumojx/

See on the right side, these content shall be invisible, because it's outside of the parent:

[image]

Few important additions:

- I can only change the divs, but not the red table itself (in case you're interested in why: it will be overwritten by JS).
- I can add some extra css properties to red table
- Red table **must** keep its `position: fixed`, and `top`, `left`, `height`, `width` values

I tried putting the red table into a div with various attributes, but nothing helped.

How can I force the fixed red table to respect its parent's borders?

Comment: `overflow:hidden` is not working?

Comment: Duplicated [parent & child with position fixed, parent overflow:hidden bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463658/parent-child-with-position-fixed-parent-overflowhidden-bug)

Comment: Instead of `overflow-x: auto` make it `overflow-x: hidden`. I think that is what you want to achieve.

Comment: For all: `overflow:hidden` does **not** work: hides the horizontal scrollbar, but keeps the red expanding over the parent. Also, I need the horizontal scrollbars to be able to scroll the gray content.

Comment: Could you describe why fixed is needed and also show relevant CSS and HTML so far.

Comment: This is part of a bigger project which I don't own, and can't control, hence `fixed` is required. However it now seems to be solved with adding `clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);` to parent. Thank you @JorgeFuentesGonzález!