# Why is my fixed div not obeying my wrapper on one side?

Tags: css, html

For some reason my fixed div at the top of my website decided to ignore my wrapper and go the right.

This is the CSS code of both my fixed div and my wrapper:

```
div.colorChanger {
background-color: #0f4a1d;
padding: 0.5%;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;}

#wrapper {
width: 1000px;
margin: -10px auto;
background-color: #78ad00;}
```

And [here](http://psichologique.com/test/index)'s what it looks like.

Comment: It won't be a stupid question if you provided a code here with some explanation instead of just saying "decided to ignore"

Comment: Your website looks good. Which div is not listening ???

Comment: @Mr.Alien I added some code.

Comment: @Harsh the colorChanger div, at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looks like your`.colorChanger` is overflowing outside your wrapper. Just use `overflow: hidden`.

Here's what that CSS would look like:

```
#wrapper {
  width:1000px;
  margin: -10px auto;
  background-color: #78ad00;
  overflow:hidden; }
```

### EDIT: Fixed position

I noticed you're using a `position: fixed` on the `.colorChanger`. Overflow [doesn't apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927583/hide-overflow-on-elements-with-fixed-position) to elements with a fixed position, so maybe you could just change it to `position: absolute` instead.

Your code should look like:

```
div.colorChanger {
  background-color: #0f4a1d;
  padding: 0.5%;
  position: absolute; // not 'fixed'
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;}

#wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: -10px auto;
  background-color: #78ad00;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; }
```

### An alternative, fixed width

Like I said, `overflow: hidden` doesn't apply to `fixed` elements. The alternative is to just use fixed width:

```
div.colorChanger {
  ...
  width: 1000px;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Comment: @PsichoLogique check out the edit. I didn't notice the `fixed` positioning at first.

Comment: I tried with both solutions and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Now it doesn't overflow but it doesn't move with the scroll like I want it to either.

Comment: I changed the position from "absolute" to "fixed" and used your solution at the same time and it worked!