# z-index issue with nested fixed elements and overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css, z-index

This seems to be a brainer, but I'll give it a try:

I have a nested element that is `position:fixed` (**.inside**) inside another element (**.bottom**) which is fixed as well and has `overflow:hidden`. I need to get the nested element get out the hidden one AND overlapping another element (**.top**) with an higher z-index as the parent element. This means: **.inside** should overlay everything.

Unfortunatly I cannot change the HTML scope nor the `z-index` values of .top and .bottom. And of course not the `overflow: hidden` …

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="inside"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

… and the CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.top {
    background: aqua;
    height: 40px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: fixed; /* important – do not change! */
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5; /* important – do not change! */
}

.bottom {
    background: green;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden; /* important – do not change! */
    position: fixed; /* important – do not change! */
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3; /* important – do not change! */
}

.inside {
    background: red;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed; /* important – do not change! */
    top: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 10; /* doesn't work! */
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c7qqtu95/1/

Comment: That positioning really make no sense. The divs aren't positioned in relaion to one another but the viewport.

Comment: `.top`  z-index  is overlapping `.bottom` z-index  just decrease `.top` z-index less then `.bottom` see this:-http://jsfiddle.net/c7qqtu95/3/

Comment: read his question again. the problem is, he cannot change the value of z-index.

Comment: With the restrictions you provide this is not possible!

Comment: .bottom has a scrolling behavior that would cause overlapping of its contents if the z-index is higher than .top.

Answer (score 4):

### Your nested element is within its parent's stacking context

Applying `overflow: hidden` to a parent with a fixed-position child [usually doesn't hide the child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927583/hide-overflow-on-elements-with-fixed-position). But the *parent element's stacking context* does have an effect on its fixed-position child elements.

The issue is that `.inside` is not independently indexed on the 'z' axis because it is part of the stacking context of its parent `.bottom`, which has its own `z-index` applied. Even without a defined `z-index`, `.bottom` would create a new stacking context because it also has `position: fixed`.

According to [MDN's documentation on stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context):

> - Positioning and assigning a z-index value to an HTML element creates a stacking context, (as does assigning non-full opacity).
> - Stacking contexts can be contained in other stacking contexts, and together create a hierarchy of stacking contexts.
> - Each stacking context is completely independent from its siblings: only descendant elements are considered when stacking is processed.
> - Each stacking context is self-contained: after the element's contents are stacked, the whole element is considered in the stacking order of the parent stacking context.

You'd have to remove `position: fixed` and `z-index` from `.bottom` for `.inside` to be within the same stacking context of `.top`.

Then your only recourse would be to use `position: absolute` on `.bottom`, at which point two of three of the properties you indicated with `/* important — do not change! */` will have been changed.

If you cannot accommodate these changes, or edit the HTML, then you have no recourse.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.top {
    background: aqua;
    height: 40px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: fixed; /* important – do not change! */
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5; /* important – do not change! */
}

.bottom {
    background: green;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden; /* important – do not change! */
    /*position: fixed; *//* important – do not change! */
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    /* z-index: 3; *//* important – do not change! */
}

.inside {
    background: red;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed; /* important – do not change! */
    top: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 10; /* this works now! */
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="inside"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so basically this is just never possible in ios? because i have it working in every browser except for ios chrome and safari. i have search page that has a drawer that is `position: fixed`, and focusing search input triggers the inputs containing element to become a `position: fixed` autocomplete. it works every where except ios, in ios the thing comes up invisible, only thing you can see is the cursor. crazy.

Comment: @r3wt I can't say without more info. But with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you could have a great SO question of your own.